# JMenuBar not showing

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem, jmenubar

I am trying to get my JMenuBar to display in the GUI, however it just appears as a 1-pixel line at the top.

This is my code...

```
public LibraryView() {
    setBounds(100,100,640,480);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JMenuBar b1 = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu m1 = new JMenu("Test");
    JMenuItem i1 = new JMenuItem("Item1");

    this.setJMenuBar(b1);
}
```

Could someone please help me to understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the `JMenu` and `JMenuItem` to the `JMenuBar`. You also need to `pack()` and `setVisible(true);` at the end of the method, just before the GUI is shown...

```
public LibraryView() {
    setBounds(100,100,640,480);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JMenuBar b1 = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu m1 = new JMenu("Test");
    JMenuItem i1 = new JMenuItem("Item1");

    m1.add(i1); // ADDED
    b1.add(m1); // ADDED

    this.setJMenuBar(b1);

    pack(); // ADDED
    setVisible(true); // MOVED
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Forgot to add the items to the bar, agh..
Could you please briefly explain why is it necessary to pack()? The code seems to work fine without it.

Comment: The majority of Java GUIs are auto-sized, meaning that they will grow and shrink depending on the size of the window and the components within it. Calling `pack()` will calculate the preferred size of the window, so that all the components can be displayed in their pressed size too. Its probably not totally necessary for you, as you've `setBounds()`, but its a good habit to call `pack()` regardless.

Comment: Thanks!
Actually after calling `pack()` the frame ignores `setBounds()` and resizes just so all the elements can fit in it.

Answer (score 3):

You should call `setVisible(true)` only ***after*** adding all components to the top level window. Also don't forget to use layout managers, to let these managers and your component's preferredSize set the sizes of components, and don't forget to call `pack()`.

Answer (score 0):

call repaint() right before you call set visible(true) this NEVER FAILS.

```
 setJMenuBar(menuBar);
 menuBar.add(jMenuItem);
 repaint(); //then
 setVisible(true); //Assured NEVER FAILS
```

Comment: Repaint() resolves the problem but it only works if you call setVisible () after it not the other way round.